# Why does validateForm display the whole table instead of the row (using JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to display email address and password for every employee by submitting their id, I used this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myMail"]["rowId"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Please type a valid National ID");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myMail" action="teamId.html" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  National ID : <input type="number" name="rowId" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Get my Mail">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

but when submitting it displays the whole table not the row that contains the employee info

and this is the first row of the table

```
<td height=53 class=xl6455 width=64 style='height:39.95pt;width:48pt'>id</td>
  <td class=xl6455 width=191 style='border-left:none;width:143pt'>National I.D</td>
  <td class=xl6555 width=390 style='border-left:none;width:293pt'>Name</td>
  <td class=xl6555 width=242 style='border-left:none;width:182pt'>E-mail
  Address</td>
  <td class=xl6555 width=221 style='border-left:none;width:166pt'>First time
  only Password</td>
  <td class=xl6555 width=200 style='border-left:none;width:150pt'>Level</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=53 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:39.95pt'>
  <td height=53 class=xl6455 style='height:39.95pt;border-top:none'>1</td>
```

Comment: You need to submit to a script that processes the form parameters and outputs the selected data. You're submitting to `teamId.html`, which is just a static HTML page.

Comment: What code do you have in `teamId.html` to process the form data? Also (FYI), replace `document.forms["myMail"]["rowId"].value;` with `document.querySelector("input[name='rowId']").value` to use modern standard DOM API's.

Comment: I have a table in this teamId.html file

Comment: That's not really what I asked. What JavaScript code is in that file that receives the form data and processes it? Please edit your question to show that code.

Comment: Ok I got it, It's just the table. I didn't think that this file should contain a Js code or functions.

Comment: Ok, that's your answer then. Yes, the file that you submit the form data to must have JS code that extracts the data that was submitted. Nothing special will automatically happen.

Comment: Ok, I added it.

Comment: Ok, so what is the code that will make this work ?

Comment: You will need some server-side code to process the submitted data. It's not just a simple matter of adding some code to the destination page. You should [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) page for details on working with forms.

Comment: I am using a host that doesn't contain a sql or database and the website was made by a builder, so i am trying to do this with js and html to pass this issue.. I just need this one page to make it ok.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea, but I still don't know what is the code that I should use for this, specially without a database to make this easier..